# "babelHelpers.asyncToGenerator is not a function" on React-Native 0.16.0 and 0.17.0

Tags: node.js, react-native, babeljs

I updated React-Native from 0.14.0 to 0.16.0 and from now, I have errors at runtime:

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3106676/11873009/b5b3aee2-a4d8-11e5-96db-831de137af06.png]

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3106676/11873609/c1cc1c34-a4db-11e5-981f-8d7d8c653819.png]

Here are the `npm dependencies`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "async": "^1.5.0",
  "immutable": "^3.7.6",
  "react-native": "^0.16.0",
  "react-native-contacts": "../../react-native-contacts",
  "react-native-contacts-rx": "^1.0.1",
  "react-native-gifted-messenger": "0.0.7",
  "react-native-i18n": "0.0.6",
  "react-redux": "^4.0.1",
  "redux": "^3.0.5",
  "rx": "^4.0.7"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0-beta6",
  "eslint": "^1.10.3",
  "eslint-config-airbnb": "^2.1.1",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.11.3",
  "events": "^1.1.0",
  "flux": "^2.1.1",
  "keymirror": "^0.1.1",
  "lodash": "^3.10.1",
  "redux-devtools": "^3.0.0"
}
```

And my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "retainLines": true,
  "compact": true,
  "comments": false,
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you overwrite any files during the update? there's an update command you should use as well. http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Questions was answered in an issue @Jean Lebrument submitted. Positing answer here for stumblers like myself...

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4844

The problem is most likely in your .babelrc file. If you experience this problem, compare your .babelrc file to [react natives default one](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/packager/react-packager/.babelrc). Try removing the file or building off of default one, adding the features that you need.

Make sure to restart your packager, stop, and re-run your project.

Comment: the link has been dead

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem you can check out what I did here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53069785/2884655

But in short I just imported the `babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator` module into my project and added it into my babelrc file