# undefined is not a function (evaluating 'babelHelpers.asyncToGenerator') react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've got this error and get stuck.

[image: error image]

I tried to remove .babelrc file but this doesn't make it work.

Comment: Same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import [babel-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-polyfill) as a first thing in your script:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue, but I fixed it by adding `transform-async-to-generator` to my .babelrc file from this babel package babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator